# Incremental sequences with interruptions

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, run-length-encoding

I have a dataset with repeating sequences of `TRUE` that I would like to label based on some conditions - by `id`, and by the sequence's incremental value.  A `FALSE` breaks the sequence of `TRUE`s and the first `FALSE` that breaks any given sequence of `TRUE` should be included in that sequence. Consecutive `FALSE`s in between `TRUE`s are irrelevant and are labeled 0.

For example:

```
> test
   id logical sequence
1   1    TRUE        1
2   1    TRUE        1
3   1   FALSE        1
4   1    TRUE        2
5   1    TRUE        2
6   1   FALSE        2
7   1    TRUE        3
8   2    TRUE        1
9   2    TRUE        1
10  2    TRUE        1
11  2   FALSE        1
12  2    TRUE        2
13  2    TRUE        2
14  2    TRUE        2
15  3   FALSE        0
16  3   FALSE        0
17  3   FALSE        0
18  3    TRUE        1
19  3   FALSE        1
20  3    TRUE        2
21  3   FALSE        2
22  3   FALSE        0
23  3   FALSE        0
24  3   FALSE        0
25  3    TRUE        3
```

And so on.  I have considered using `rle()` which produces

```
> rle(test$logical)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:13] 2 1 2 1 4 1 3 3 1 1 ...
  values : logi [1:13] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
```

But I am not sure how to map this back on the data frame.  Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Here are the sample data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), logical = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("id", "logical"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

Comment: hmm, what is not clear?

Comment: the first FALSE that breaks any given sequence of TRUE should be included in the sequence, does that make sense?  Where `id =1`, it is the case because if the first sequence of 2 TRUE is broken by one FALSE which is included in the first sequence (first sequence is 3 rows), and the second sequence is also 3 rows because there are two TRUES broken by one FALSE.

Comment: thanks @akrun I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: yeah, it is better now

Comment: not that easy but functions that could help you are: `lag`, `rleidv`, `cumsum`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pure `data.table` solution:

```
# load the 'data.table'-package & convert 'test' to a data.table with 'setDT'
library(data.table)
setDT(test)

# calculate the new sequence
test[, new_seq := (rleid(logical) - !logical) * !(!logical & !shift(logical, fill = FALSE)), by = id
     ][new_seq != 0, new_seq := rleid(new_seq), by = id][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     id logical new_seq
>  1:  1    TRUE       1
>  2:  1    TRUE       1
>  3:  1   FALSE       1
>  4:  1    TRUE       2
>  5:  1    TRUE       2
>  6:  1   FALSE       2
>  7:  1    TRUE       3
>  8:  2    TRUE       1
>  9:  2    TRUE       1
> 10:  2    TRUE       1
> 11:  2   FALSE       1
> 12:  2    TRUE       2
> 13:  2    TRUE       2
> 14:  2    TRUE       2
> 15:  3   FALSE       0
> 16:  3   FALSE       0
> 17:  3   FALSE       0
> 18:  3    TRUE       1
> 19:  3   FALSE       1
> 20:  3    TRUE       2
> 21:  3   FALSE       2
> 22:  3   FALSE       0
> 23:  3   FALSE       0
> 24:  3   FALSE       0
> 25:  3    TRUE       3
> ```

What this does:

- `rleid(logical) - !logical` creates a numeric run length id and substracts `1` for where `logical` is equal to `FALSE`
- The result of the previous step is then multiplied with the result of `!(!logical & !shift(logical, fill = FALSE))`, which is a `TRUE`/`FALSE` vector for consequtive `FALSE` values except the first one of a `FALSE`-sequence.
- Finally, we create a new run length id for only the rows where `new_seq` is not equal to `0` and have your desired result.

---

A slightly improved alternative (as suggested by @jogo in the comments):

```
test[, new_seq := (rleid(logical) - !logical) * (logical | shift(logical, fill = FALSE)), by = id
     ][new_seq != 0, new_seq := rleid(new_seq), by = id][]
```

Comment: @jogo looked at it & it is indeed a nice improvement!

Answer (score 3):

There is for sure a better implementation of `makeSeq` function but this works.

This one uses libraries `data.table`, `magrittr` and `dplyr`

**Function**

```
makeSeq <- function(x) {
    res  <- ifelse(!x&!lag(x,default = F),T,x) %>% {!.} %>% lag(default=T) %>% cumsum
    IND2F<- ifelse(!x&!lag(x,default = F),T,x) != x
    res[IND2F]  <- 0
    res[!IND2F] <- rleidv(res[!IND2F])
    return(res)
}
```

**data.table solution**

```
setDT(df)[,yourSEQ:=makeSeq(logical),by="id"]
df
```

**tidyverse fans use**

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(yourSEQ = makeSeq(logical)) %>% ungroup
```

**Result**

```
> df
    id logical yourSEQ
 1:  1    TRUE       1
 2:  1    TRUE       1
 3:  1   FALSE       1
 4:  1    TRUE       2
 5:  1    TRUE       2
 6:  1   FALSE       2
 7:  1    TRUE       3
 8:  2    TRUE       1
 9:  2    TRUE       1
10:  2    TRUE       1
11:  2   FALSE       1
12:  2    TRUE       2
13:  2    TRUE       2
14:  2    TRUE       2
15:  3   FALSE       0
16:  3   FALSE       0
17:  3   FALSE       0
18:  3    TRUE       1
19:  3   FALSE       1
20:  3    TRUE       2
21:  3   FALSE       2
22:  3   FALSE       0
23:  3   FALSE       0
24:  3   FALSE       0
25:  3    TRUE       3
    id logical yourSEQ
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `cumsum` for your `rle` values, then you have to go back and fix the sequential `FALSE` values.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(sum_rle = with(rle(logical), rep(cumsum(values), lengths))) %>% 
  mutate(sequence2 = if_else(logical == F & lag(logical) == F, 0L, sum_rle, missing = 0L)) %>% 
  print(n = 25)

# # A tibble: 25 x 5
# # Groups:   id [3]
#       id logical sequence sum_rle sequence2
#    <int> <lgl>      <int>   <int>     <int>
#  1     1 TRUE           1       1         1
#  2     1 TRUE           1       1         1
#  3     1 FALSE          1       1         1
#  4     1 TRUE           2       2         2
#  5     1 TRUE           2       2         2
#  6     1 FALSE          2       2         2
#  7     1 TRUE           3       3         3
#  8     2 TRUE           1       1         1
#  9     2 TRUE           1       1         1
# 10     2 TRUE           1       1         1
# 11     2 FALSE          1       1         1
# 12     2 TRUE           2       2         2
# 13     2 TRUE           2       2         2
# 14     2 TRUE           2       2         2
# 15     3 FALSE          0       0         0
# 16     3 FALSE          0       0         0
# 17     3 FALSE          0       0         0
# 18     3 TRUE           1       1         1
# 19     3 FALSE          1       1         1
# 20     3 TRUE           2       2         2
# 21     3 FALSE          2       2         2
# 22     3 FALSE          0       2         0
# 23     3 FALSE          0       2         0
# 24     3 FALSE          0       2         0
# 25     3 TRUE           3       3         3
```

if you prefer a really concise version of the same thing...

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(test, id) %>%
  mutate(sequence = if_else(!logical & !lag(logical), 0L, 
                            with(rle(logical), rep(cumsum(values), lengths)), 
                            missing = 0L))
```

Comment: FYI, `logical == FALSE` = `!logical`

Answer (score 2):

without using rle in `dtmtd2` and also some timings:

```
dplyrmtd0 <- function() {
    test %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(sum_rle = with(rle(logical), rep(cumsum(values), lengths))) %>% 
        mutate(sequence2 = if_else(logical == F & lag(logical) == F, 0L, sum_rle, missing = 0L))
}

setDT(test)    
makeSeq <- function(x) {
    res  <- ifelse(!x&!lag(x,default = F),T,x) %>% {!.} %>% lag(default=T) %>% cumsum
    IND2F<- ifelse(!x&!lag(x,default = F),T,x) != x
    res[IND2F]  <- 0
    res[!IND2F] <- rleidv(res[!IND2F])
    return(res)
}
dt0 <- copy(test)
dtmtd0 <- function() {
    dt0[,yourSEQ:=makeSeq(logical),by="id"]   
}

dt1 <- copy(test)
dtmtd1 <- function() {
    dt1[, new_seq := (rleid(logical) - !logical) * !(!logical & !shift(logical, fill = FALSE)), by = id
        ][new_seq != 0, new_seq := rleid(new_seq), by = id][]   
}

dt4 <- copy(test)
dtmtd2 <- function() {
    dt4[, sequence := {
            idx <- cumsum(diff(c(FALSE, logical))==1L)
            mask <- shift(logical, fill=FALSE) | logical
            idx * mask
        }, by=id]
}

microbenchmark(dplyrmtd0(), dtmtd0(), dtmtd1(), dtmtd2(), times=5L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 dplyrmtd0() 375.6089 376.7271 433.1885 380.7428 443.8844 588.9791     5
    dtmtd0() 481.5189 487.1245 492.9527 495.6855 500.1588 500.2759     5
    dtmtd1() 146.0376 147.0163 154.7501 152.7157 154.2976 173.6831     5
    dtmtd2() 106.3401 107.7728 112.7580 108.5239 119.4398 121.7131     5
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
M <- 1e6
test <- data.frame(id=sample(LETTERS, M, replace=TRUE) ,
    logical=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), M, replace=TRUE))
test <- test[order(test$id),]
```